# Multiple XSLT Transformations on XML File Using Ant

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, xslt-2.0

So i have an XML file that i need to run multiple transformations on to create various sections of a webpage using an ANT target and the saxon9he transformer. There are a lot of transformations to run so they have been split up into seperate files.

So far i have this which works fine for 1 transformation file:

```
<target name="transform">
    <xslt       
    basedir="INPUT/"
    destdir="OUTPUT/
    includes="myfile.xml"
    style="INPUT/XSLT/generateSection1.xsl"
    classpath="saxon9he.jar;"> 

        <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" /> 

    </xslt>
</target>
```

I realise that in order to run multiple XSLT files from this target i could run one XSLT file that uses `<xsl:import>`'s to import all the other files i need but i was just wondering if it was possible to run all the XSLT files in a particular folder using something like `style="Input/XSLT/*.xsl"` and if so would this have a negative effect on performance ?

Comment: have a look at xmltask http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/

Comment: for anyone interested i solved this using a for loop courtesy of the ant-contrib library http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this in Ant, but note that Ant pipelines are never going to be super-efficient because tasks always work on files and not on in-memory objects. So if several transformations use the same file as input, it's going to be parsed several times. In theory you should get better performance out of a pipeline tool that's more oriented to XML workflows, e.g. an XProc engine like Calabash. (Having said that, I use Ant all the time and it's fast enough for the things I use it for.)